# merge same keys data into one map with unique keys elixir

Tags: elixir

I have this json

```
[
  %{
    "159.69.136.31" => [
      %{"2015" => ["4"]},
      %{"2016" => []},
      %{"2017" => ["9"]},
      %{"2018" => []},
      %{"2019" => ["05"]}
    ]
  },
  %{ 
    "94.130.139.38" => [
      %{"2015" => []},
      %{"2016" => []},
      %{"2017" => []},
      %{"2018" => ["5", "8"]},
      %{"2019" => []}
    ]
  },
  %{
    "94.130.217.56" => [
      %{"2015" => []},
      %{"2016" => []},
      %{"2017" => []},
      %{"2018" => []},
      %{"2019" => []}
    ]
  }
]
```

and I want to make it something like

```
[
  %{"2015" => ["4"]},
  %{"2016" => []},
  %{"2017" => ["9"]},
  %{"2018" => ["5", "8"]},
  %{"2019" => ["05"]}
]
```

Basically, it's merging the same year's keys and the data available on the map. I have tried this solution with different approaches but it didn't work [Elixir: Merge list with same map keys to one map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46517703/elixir-merge-list-with-same-map-keys-to-one-map)

Update: years and IPs are constant
Update little bit more info about this..

```
years = ["2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"]
servers = [@seaweedfs_new, @seaweedfs_old, @seaweedfs_oldest]

  Enum.map(servers, fn server ->
    type = seaweefs_type(server)
    attribute = seaweedfs_attribute(server)
    url = "http://" <> server <> ":8888" <> "/#{camera.exid}/snapshots/recordings/"
    year_values =
      Enum.map(years, fn year ->
        final_url = url <> year <> "/"
        %{
          "#{year}" => request_from_seaweedfs(final_url, type, attribute)
        }
      end)
    %{
      "#{server}" => year_values
    }
  end)
```

This is how I am getting year values and making them to the server object. If there is a possibility to break it down while even getting year values?

`"#{year}" => request_from_seaweedfs(final_url, type, attribute)` this request basically returns such as `"2015"  => ["1", "2", "3"]`, is there any possiblity to merge years a head before going to into servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get to the flat list of maps and then merge all of them.

```rb
input
|> Enum.flat_map(&Map.values/1)
|> Enum.flat_map(& &1)
|> Enum.reduce(&Map.merge(&1, &2, fn _, v1, v2 ->
  v1 ++ v2
end))
#⇒ %{
#    "2015" => ["4"],
#    "2016" => [],
#    "2017" => ["9"],
#    "2018" => ["5", "8"],
#    "2019" => ["05"]
# }
```

---

To get a list of maps (which is IMHO the wrong design decision,) just do:

```rb
for {k, v} <- map, do: %{k => v}
#⇒ [
#    %{"2015" => ["4"]},
#    %{"2016" => []},
#    %{"2017" => ["9"]},
#    %{"2018" => ["5", "8"]},
#    %{"2019" => ["05"]}
# ]
```

Comment: It will not really mean anything to you, But I always look for your advice in Elixir and literally follow what you always suggest. Thanks for your answer mudasobwa.

Comment: Glad to be of any help.

Comment: @JunaidFarooq, Just so you know, this answer traverses the list 1, 2, 3, times then has to do merging of maps on top of that, then does the conversion from map to list. Even Aleksei would tell you that isn't the most efficient answer.

Comment: @7stud I second ⬆️ (well, yours still traverses the map once.)

Comment: @7stud but this map has _years_ as keys. Which obviously means readability is way more important than performance.

Comment: I have a question while doing all this flat_map, reduce and merge can we do something like make this, `["5", "8", "8"]` to this `["5", "8"]`, I am getting duplicate values in the list of months.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, how to make Y from X, here's a quick-and-dirty solution:

```
data = [
  %{
    "159.69.136.31" => [
      %{"2015" => ["4"]},
      %{"2016" => []},
      %{"2017" => ["9"]},
      %{"2018" => []},
      %{"2019" => ["05"]}
    ]
  },
  %{
    "94.130.139.38" => [
      %{"2015" => []},
      %{"2016" => []},
      %{"2017" => []},
      %{"2018" => ["5", "8"]},
      %{"2019" => []}
    ]
  },
  %{
    "94.130.217.56" => [
      %{"2015" => []},
      %{"2016" => []},
      %{"2017" => []},
      %{"2018" => []},
      %{"2019" => []}
    ]
  }
]
```

code:

```
data
|> Enum.map(&Map.values/1)
|> List.flatten
|> Enum.map(fn year_map -> year_map |> Map.to_list |> hd end)
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn {year, year_data}, acc ->
  Map.update(acc, year, year_data, &[&1 | year_data])
end)
|> Enum.map(fn {year, year_data} ->
  {year, List.flatten(year_data) |> Enum.reject(&is_nil/1)}
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

returns:

```
[
  {"2015", ["4"]},
  {"2016", []},
  {"2017", ["9"]},
  {"2018", ["5", "8"]},
  {"2019", ["05"]}
]
```

Insert more `IO.inspect`s in the pipeline and functions to see what transformations are going on.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing:

```
"#{server}" => year_values
```

when you don't care about the server name in the final result?  Doing that makes it harder to access the relevant data.

You can use a `for loop` (which is also called a list comprehension) coupled with the `:reduce` option (elixir 1.8+) to create a results map:

```
defmodule My do

  @years ["2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"]
  @servers ["new", "old", "oldest"] 

  def request_from_seaweedfs(url, _type, _attribute) do
    IO.puts url
    "#{:random.uniform(20)}"  #Returns a random string
  end

  def get_data do
    for server <- @servers, year <- @years, reduce: %{} do
      map -> #This is the map specified here --------^
        url = "http://#{server}:8888/camera.exid/snapshots/recordings/#{year}/"
        result = request_from_seaweedfs(url, "x", "y")
        IO.puts "#{year}: #{result}"
        Map.update(map, year, [result], &([result|&1]))
    end
  end

end
```

Output:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex my.ex
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Interactive Elixir (1.8.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> My.get_data
http://new:8888/camera.exid/snapshots/recordings/2015/
2015: 9
http://new:8888/camera.exid/snapshots/recordings/2016/
2016: 15
http://new:8888/camera.exid/snapshots/recordings/2017/
2017: 19
http://new:8888/camera.exid/snapshots/recordings/2018/
2018: 11
http://new:8888/camera.exid/snapshots/recordings/2019/
2019: 7
http://old:8888/camera.exid/snapshots/recordings/2015/
2015: 12
http://old:8888/camera.exid/snapshots/recordings/2016/
2016: 19
http://old:8888/camera.exid/snapshots/recordings/2017/
2017: 14
http://old:8888/camera.exid/snapshots/recordings/2018/
2018: 10
http://old:8888/camera.exid/snapshots/recordings/2019/
2019: 12
http://oldest:8888/camera.exid/snapshots/recordings/2015/
2015: 3
http://oldest:8888/camera.exid/snapshots/recordings/2016/
2016: 5
http://oldest:8888/camera.exid/snapshots/recordings/2017/
2017: 14
http://oldest:8888/camera.exid/snapshots/recordings/2018/
2018: 4
http://oldest:8888/camera.exid/snapshots/recordings/2019/
2019: 12

%{
  "2015" => ["3", "12", "9"],
  "2016" => ["5", "19", "15"],
  "2017" => ["14", "14", "19"],
  "2018" => ["4", "10", "11"],
  "2019" => ["12", "12", "7"]
}
```

To get your list, you can do:

```
My.get_data |> Enum.map(fn {key,val} -> %{key => val} end)
```

which produces:

```
[
  %{"2015" => ["3", "12", "9"]},
  %{"2016" => ["5", "19", "15"]},
  %{"2017" => ["14", "14", "19"]},
  %{"2018" => ["4", "10", "11"]},
  %{"2019" => ["12", "12", "7"]}
]
```

And, if the data's order needs to be maintained then you can do:

```
My.get_data |> Enum.map(fn {key,val} -> %{key => Enum.reverse(val)} end)
```

Comment: what will final results look like?

Comment: @JunaidFarooq, It's all right there in the output.  Did you scroll down?  Do you really want a list like in your question?  A list just makes it harder to access the data.

Comment: Yes thank I have scrolled down but I need a list, in the end as written :)

Comment: @JunaidFarooq, See the conversion to a list at the bottom of my answer.